# Use Categories/Tags in non-Post pages too

Tags: jekyll

I have been searching for a way to use the tagging feature available in jekyll Posts, but in any page on the site, not just in pages contained inside the _posts directory.

As far as I can tell, when I specify a *tags* value in the YAML front matter of a page that is not in _posts, these tags are then accessible from the *page.tags* variable, but not from *site.tags*, which makes it hard then to have a separate tags.html page summarizing all tags from all pages.

Any idea how to deal with that?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so it seems that there is no built-in way to leverage tags from pages, so in case someone stumbles upon this thread, I finally rolled my own jekyll plugin code to do it, based on this great blog entry, with very little modifications:

http://brizzled.clapper.org/blog/2010/12/20/some-jekyll-hacks/

Comment: I was hoping this problem was solvable using a Rakefile. My Jekyll blog currently has zero *.rb files and zero plugins, but a sizable Rakefil that does all the tag/category parsing. What do you think, is it possible?

Comment: I guess so, based on something like this: https://github.com/mattfoster/mattfoster.github.com/blob/master/Rakefile, and using read_directories to parse not only posts but all pages ? I am not familiar enough with rakefile to be sure.